# In Javascript can you use a set of document.write's and store them as one variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Just a quick question which is basically to do with document.write.
Again new to this so apologies in advance if it is a daft question.

Are you able to convert document.write into a variable if all the document.write's was nested in a for loop?

For example existing code is:

```
                  for (loop = number; loop >0; loop--) 
        {
                      
          factorial = factorial*loop ;
          if (loop!=1)
          {
          document.write (loop +"x");
          } 
          else 
          { //otherwise put in the loop = string
          document.write (loop+"=");
          } 
                            
        } 
        document.write (factorial +"<br>");
```

So you would then have document.write the full answer as '4x3x2x1=24' which works when the program ends and displays.

Could you store that whole set of document.write's as a variable to display in javascript as an alert.

So it would look something like:

```
        var fullFactorial = all document.write
        alert (fullFactorial);
```

I'm just not sure if its do-able and any help would be ace.

Comment: Why can't you just concatenate final output to one variable?

Comment: *can you store document.write* - no, document.write writes to the document.   *can you use a variable then output that variable in a single document.write* - absolutely.

Comment: *use a set of document.write's and store them as one variable* — …what?

Comment: Don't use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), take a look at [Document manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Answer (score -1):

`document.write` expects a string as an argument, so you can build up the string in your loop and then do a single call to `document.write`; see `***` comments:

```js
const number = 10;
let factorial = 1;
let str = ""; // *** The string we'll build; starts empty
for (let loop = number; loop > 0; loop--) {
    factorial = factorial * loop;
    if (loop != 1) {
        str += loop + "x"; // *** Add to the string
    } else {
        //otherwise put in the loop = string
        str += loop + " = "; // *** Add to the string
    }
}
str += factorial; // *** Add to the string
document.write(str + "<br>"); // Output the string and a <br>
```

That said, I **strongly urge** you not to use `document.write`. Use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) instead. For instance:

```js
const number = 10;
let factorial = 1;
let steps = "";
for (let loop = number; loop > 0; loop--) {
    factorial = factorial * loop;
    if (loop != 1) {
        steps += loop + "x";
    } else {
        steps += loop;
    }
}
document.getElementById("steps").textContent = steps;
document.getElementById("result").textContent = factorial;
```

```html
<span id="steps"></span> = <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, `document.write` is very much obsolete, please use something else.

But to answer your question, just build a variable first by concatenating everything you want to concatenate, and then insert it into the DOM. Then you'll still have it in a variable.